# React TransitionGroup children based on state

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

At the moment I have a number of the same component that is rendered from a map like so:

```
{this.state.Tweets.map(t => <Tweet key={t.title} title={t.title} desc={t.desc} />)}
```

So what I've done is wrapped the entire map object with a transition as such:

`<TransitionGroup>
{this.state.Tweets.map(t => <Tweet key={t.title} title={t.title} desc={t.desc} />)}
</TransitionGroup>`

`this.state.tweets` is updated with the following:

```
filterTweets() {
  const t = this.state.tweets;
  const filteredTweets = _.filter(t, tweet => tweet.time.end > this.state.time);
  this.setState({ tweets: filteredTweets });
}
```

However when `this.state.Tweets` is updated for whatever reason the number of items within the `<TransitionGroup>` does not update. I can get `componentWillEnter` lifecycle hook to fire but I can't get anything else to update. Any ideas?

I've tried adding `this.state.Tweets` as a prop to `<TransitionGroup>` but that didn't seem to work at all.

Comment: how are you changing this.state.Tweets?

Comment: @Turnipdabeets I've updated my post to include how I'm updating this.state.Tweets

Comment: Wouldn't you want `this.setState({ tweets: filteredTweets });` instead of `this.setState({ tweets: filtered });` ?

Comment: @Turnipdabeets Ah yes. Thats just an error with my StackOverflow example. Sorry about that.

Comment: Do you have a link to your source code I can look at?

Comment: @Turnipdabeets Unfortunately I wish I did. Any ideas?

Comment: It might not be that helpful but I'd try pulling the map logic out into a variable and place that inside `<TransitionGroup>`. Probably won't do anything but maybe there's something strange happening in <TransitionGroup>. Then I'd console.log everything to follow this.state.tweets to see what happens. maybe something async is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had missed a crucial role of the TransitionGroup:

> Note that you must call the supplied callbacks after your animation ends, otherwise your component will enter but not leave, or leave but not enter.